# Google Annotation Chart Duplicates Itself

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I haven't seen this problem with other Google charts before but I am using the Annotation Chart and every time the data is updated the following lines are called which duplicates the chart object in the DOM as a sibling of the parent:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_' + this.display.displayDivId));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

This more or less makes sense based on the code but how can I prevent the new method from firing and instead create a chart object out of the existing DOM element and then call the .draw() method on that object?

Is this possible?  The only other thing I can think of would be to clear the existing one from the DOM first, and then proceed w/ the logic I illustrated above.

Any thoughts/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: At this point I have just deleted the duplicate child node after calling draw and fortunately it fires fast enough you don't see it.  I don't however love this solution...

Comment: Why don't you just call `chart.draw(data, options);` for update. You need `var chart...` only first time. There is also `clearChart()` method if it is necessary to get rid of resources.